# "Execution failed for task: ':app:javaPreCompileDebug' " in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I get the following errors when trying to execute my project:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
>
> > Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain
> >     annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor
> >     configuration.
> >         - butterknife-7.0.1.jar (com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1)   Alternatively, set
> >     android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath
> >     = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.   See
> >     https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html
> >     for more details.

Please don't mark this question as duplicate as other question regrading this, here, is for lombok, which I'm not using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you need to use `annotationProcessor` in your app build.gradle. Afaik, you need to upgrade the ButterKnife library to version **8.8.1**. You need to use something like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

Please check [Android studio 3.0 butterknife error](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/963) issue for the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I did it, then the error I was getting was "Can't resolve symbol Bind". On googling, I found that 'Bind' had to be replaced with 'BindView'. I did that in all activities. Then the error I got was "Can't resolve method 'getMap()". Found that getMap() is depreciated by google and had to be replaced with getMapAsync(). 
Now I'm unable to solve this as I'm not sure how to implement it.
The error is regarding the arguments to it. Unable to resolve it.

Comment: I'm trying to implement it this way:

private GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps))
            .getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                            .title("Marker"));

                }
            });

The error I get is :

Error:(52, 25) error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to GoogleMap

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me. Gotta love quick fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the following process makes my problem solved.

In the build.gradle(module app)

1. apply the plugin:

   ```
    apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
   ```
2. Add the following lines in the dependencies section:

   ```
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
   ```

In the build.gradle(Project:projectName), add the classPath in the dependencies like this :

```
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'
```

It will fix this issue.
In case if not then add maven:

```
 maven {
 url 'https://maven.google.com'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Adding these two line in app/build.gradle 

dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}


It worked for me
```

Comment: @PareshMangukiya Because it repeats the solution of [the existing 2.5 years old answer by ישו אוהב אותך](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48416813/466862) and [the one by meyasir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281759/466862).